# Enable control in disabled panel using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disabled-control

Does anyone know a way to enable a control (more specifically, a div having the class '.nf-attachment-control'), if this div is contained within **another** div that has to remain disabled?

PS: I'm using jQuery within a Nintex Form (hence the .nf class), but this fact should have no impact on the question above. What I'm looking for is a way to bypass the implicit 'disabled' property inheritance in HTML.

Is this even possible??

Comment: It might be possible, but in UI terms this makes no sense. A disabled control is disabled and internal controls inside should also be disabled. That is intuitive and what users expect out of HTML and their browser experience.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think this is possible. All child controls are disabled when their parent is disabled, you need to find a different way of solving your problem. Re-parenting the control div is an option or dynamically enabling the parent.